# Equivalent of ctx.translate in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm new to Fabric.js
When using Canvas, I have these lines of code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(100, 100);
```

`ctx.translate(100, 100);` used to move the Coordinate to the left and bottom 100px. I am wondering if there is a equivalent in Fabric.js
Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Can you be more specific on what do you need translate for? there is no direct translate equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent for this.
Fabricjs use ctx.translate to position the objects at theyr `top` and `left` property.

If you need to place a circle at [200, 200], instead of doing

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(200, 200);
/* circle drawing here */
```

you will do

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 50});
circle.top = 200;
circle.left = 200;
canvas.add(circle);
```